# How do I loop through elements of a bash array variable passed to a Ruby script via terminal?

Tags: arrays, ruby, linux, bash, parameter-passing

I have a Bash file called `test.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
arr=(whatever@gmail.com iamcool@gmail.com)
ruby testScript.rb $arr
```

And here's `testScript.rb`:

```
ARGV.each{|a| p a}
```

When I run `./test.sh` in the terminal, I get this output:

```
"whatever@gmail.com"
```

I want my Ruby script to loop through all elements in the Bash array variable `$arr`. How do I fix my code to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the bash script, pass the array like this:

```
ruby testScript.rb "${arr[@]}"
```

Comment: Quotes! Quotes are your friend. Use them: `ruby testScript.rb "${arr[@]}"`.